# Interaction Design Role

Tags: jobs, roles

I'm getting more and more confused by the different job titles out there …

Especially the Interaction Designer is used indifferently I find regarding the visual design aspect. As per my understanding the IxD is responsible for the conceptual / functional design - delivering wireframes and prototypes. But here and there it seems   that visual design is part of that role  as well.

Is there a clear definition ?

Answer (score 3):

[Here is a great article from fastcodesign](http://www.fastcodesign.com/3032719/ui-ux-who-does-what-a-designers-guide-to-the-tech-industry) that I think explains it really well.

Here is a an excerpt:

> #### INTERACTION DESIGNER (MOTION DESIGNER)
>
> Remember the subtle bouncing
> animation when you pull to refresh in the Mail app on your iPhone?
> That's the work of a motion designer. Unlike visual designers who
> usually deal with static assets, motion designers create animation
> inside an app. They deal with what the interface does after a user
> touches it. For example, they decide how a menu should slide in, what
> transition effects to use, and how a button should fan out. When done
> well, motion becomes an integral part of the interface by providing
> visual clues as to how to use the product.

However, as with many of these 'newer' design roles, many people that work in these positions often wear a number of different hats - It can be difficult for a smaller company to justify employing someone solely for Interaction design. So you might find that a visual designer, or UI designer, or someone else is doing the role of an interaction designer and vice versa.